# hover event on touch device

Tags: html, css

I decrease opacity of `<ul>` when mouse over the `<ul>` tag area and then set full opacity for `<li>` which user is on that.

like this sample:
[Image change opacity on hover without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435158/image-change-opacity-on-hover-without-jquery)

now, the problem is in tablet and phones, because on touch devices we don't have hover event and user should click (touch) on `<li>` so all another `<li>` will decrease the opacity and user cannot unselect (unhover) that `<li>` so they should refresh the page.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you taken a look here? Apple lists what their browser can and can not do in touch events. Take a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On touch devices, `hover` is not supported. You can either:

• skip hover effects in touch device stylesheets
• use JavaScript to turn hover into click interactions
• use JavaScript to simulate hover interactions on the touch device

There are multiple other posts on SO that discuss about this problem:

[How do I simulate a hover with a touch in touch enabled browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers)
[how to deal with hover effect on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259848/how-to-deal-with-hover-effect-on-touch-devices)
[Hover for Touch Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999069/hover-for-touch-devices?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Since `:hover` is of course not supported in touch only browsers, you can use the touchStart, touchMove, and touchEnd events (through javascript). These are used very well in the FastClick library.

Also some CSS `:hover` events can be activated through a touch only browser if you hold your finger on the screen.

Comment: Any solution to working `:hover` in touch only browser?

Answer (score -2):

A bit late...

but you could use css animations to show the menu for 4-5 seconds before hiding it again...

not perfect but you get rid of the JS .. not that js is wrong, i use angularJS..

EDIT: -- were asked to ref hers a link http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337