# Css :hover without "click" event for touch devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say i have this html structure:

```
<div className="big-square">
    <div className="small-button">button</div>
</div>
```

I need to show the button on `.big-square:hover`. It's simple, but what about touch devices? If i'll use simply `.big-square:hover` css rule, then if user will accidentally click at the location of button, then button will appear and will be clicked instantly. I want to avoid this situation. I've tried to use misc transition delays, but this doesn't work.

Here an example, to make it easier to understand and answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/hznjb8ur/

Jquery is there for sake of simplicity. I would like to avoid using jquery and even js for this case, because i have dozens and hundreds elements like that on a single page, so i'd prefer to solve this with simple css trick.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261961/hover-event-on-touch-device?rq=1

Comment: I have tried :hover and it also working with click event on touch device

Comment: you can use media query

Comment: Making touch devices work with `:hover` is weird. Touch devices are totally different from pointer devices in perspective of interaction. I'm afraid you are going a wrong way. I'd try to figure out a better design, rather than hack a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The actual "touchables" devices don't support hover because the screens don't know about the pointer (finger or anything else) position.

Microsoft actually is working on that http://www.theverge.com/2016/5/5/11595564/microsoft-3d-touch-kinect-gestures-windows-phones maybe in a near future we can see that behaviour

Answer (score -1):

`:hover` is not supported by touch devices. `:hover` functions will only be activated when you click on it on touchscreens.

Why not displaying the button on touch devices instead of hiding it?
Else only jquery can help you.

Comment: "only jquery can help you" ... God save us all.

Comment: I dont know who downvoted but its nothing than the truth i wrote :/

Comment: Well, it is an answer. The awnser is that touch devices dont support :hover events (yet) and that javascript can help to make a workaround